# how to use gdb to debug a plugin

Tags: c++, gdb

I am trying to debug, with gdb, a plugin to a program.  I saw a question earlier that indicated that the directory command in gdb might help.  I thought it would help because, when I try to set a breakpoint within the code of the plugin, I get the error that says: "No source file named..."  It didn't seem to do anything when I used the directory command with the source path structure.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: [StackOverflow is not a Tools Tutorial.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134609/142865)

Comment: True.  I will go through the tutorial first, and then ask.  I didn't think to look up tutorials for some reason.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem, hope you find what you're looking for.  By the way, you might want to check out superuser.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "No source file named..."

GDB will not be able to set a breakpoint until your plugin is *actually* loaded into the inferior (being debugged) process.

Use `(gdb) info shared` command to check whether your plugin is already loaded or not.

If it isn't, you can set a "deferred" breakpoint (GDB should be asking you whether you want to set such a breakpoint, assuming you have the default `set confirm on` setting).

If your plugin is already loaded and visible in `info shared` output, then you haven't built your plugin with debug info. Rebuild it with `-g`, and you should be able to set breakpoints in it.